# Unable to find a specification for `UMPermissionsInterface` depended upon by `EXAV`

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

We are getting the following error when trying to generate an IOS build.

Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `UMPermissionsInterface` depended upon by `EXAV`

You have either:

- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

\

We have tried the following:

Open RNPermissions.podspec in node_modules/react-native-permissions replace s.dependency "React-Core" with s.dependency "React/Core".

and

pod 'RNPermissions', :path =>  '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

But still not working.